# trying to upgrade from 19.04 to 20.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I'm trying to upgrade from 19.04 to 20.04 and I always get this:

```
ERROR: failed to read '/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades': Source contains parsing errors: '/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades' [line 11]: 'x# currently-running release.\n'
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: There is no upgrade path from 19.04 to 20.04.

Comment: well I had seen them before, but as I'm stupid, I can't get what I  should do to get my update manager to do what it should...

Comment: The only recommended way is to do a fresh install. The update-manager "should not" do what you want.

Comment: Read your output: You have an error on line 11 of /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades. Open that file in a text editor and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article which might be helpful: https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-ubuntu-version

Try doing:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

This worked for me.

Comment: well, there I get this message...ERROR: failed to read '/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades':
Source contains parsing errors: '/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades'
 [line 11]: 'x#           currently-running release.\n'